# curl not downloading all pdf files PHP

Tags: php, curl

im trying to download multiple pdfs with php. i get an array of urls and each url redirects to a website that contains a pdf file if something is wrong with that url it just redirects to a html page, so i've been googling and found this to download all pdfs to the server:

```
public function download ($data, $simultaneous = 1, $save_to)
    {
        $loops = array_chunk($data, $simultaneous, true);

        foreach ($loops as $key => $value)
        {
            foreach ($value as $urlkey => $urlvalue)
            {
                $ch[$urlkey] = curl_init($urlvalue["url"]);
                curl_setopt($ch[$urlkey], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch[$urlkey], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch[$urlkey], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            }

            $mh = curl_multi_init();

            foreach ($value as $urlkey => $urlvalue)
            {
                curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$urlkey]);
            }

            $running = null;
            do {
                curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
            } while ($running);

            foreach ($value as $urlkey => $urlvalue)
            {
                $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$urlkey]);
                file_put_contents($save_to.$urlvalue["saveas"], $response);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$ch[$urlkey]);
                curl_close($ch[$urlkey]);
            }

        }
    }
```

for some reason this downloads only some of the files 
[image]

anyone has any idea why this is not working? 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: check returned status from curl_multi_exec ().... $status = curl_multi_exec and.. if $status  != CURLM_OK  keep trying

Comment: I think maybe add try catch statement and a sleep(1) between requests just to see if it makes a diff; process of elimination

Comment: @Mate i added $status to my code but i got the same result.

Comment: @IlanP can you explain where to add sleep(1)? should i add it after i use curl_close?

Comment: What $status did you get ?

Comment: @Mate i got a lot of "0"s

Comment: In that cases sleep(1) and try again